# How do I fix No such module issue in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyYoy.jpg)

I cloned project, Installed pods and I ran it but I keep getting this error.
And If I remove Import code, I get another No such model error constantly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f9cy.jpg)

I am running xcworkspace file
I tried deleting xcworkspace file, pod file, pod.lock and reinstalled pods.
I also tried Rosetta mode, pod setup, pod update.
Almost tried everything but still does not work.
My teammate sent his code and I ran it on my Mac it was also not working.
I reinstalled Xcode several times.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwzrQ.png)
I guess my laptop configuration problem
I got new Mac book 2023 m2 chip and right away downloaded Xcode nothing changed in Xcode.
please help me, give me advice anything I can try

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9Ayd.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caAWZ.png)

I tried almost everything
this is my pod file below.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for     your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ASI' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic     frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ASI
  
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.0'
  pod 'KeychainSwift', '~> 11.0'
  pod 'AAPickerView'

  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'FirebaseDatabase'
  pod 'FirebaseStorage'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'MessageKit', '~> 3.0.0'
  pod 'MessageInputBar'
  pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper'
  pod 'iOSDropDown'
  pod 'CountryPickerView'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'
  pod 'Toast-Swift', '~> 4.0.0'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'JGProgressHUD'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
  pod 'SKCountryPicker'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'PusherSwift'
  pod 'Eureka'
  pod 'CropViewController'
  pod 'SDWebImage'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod "SwiftSignatureView", '~> 3.2.0'
  pod 'DropDown'
  pod 'DatePickerDialog'
  pod 'Amplify'
  pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSS3StoragePlugin'
  pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSCognitoAuthPlugin'
  pod 'Optik'
  pod 'AlamofireImage'
  pod 'SideMenu'
  pod 'SVProgressHUD'
#  pod "RxSwift"
#  pod "RxCocoa"
post_install do |installer|
    installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
          project.targets.each do |target|
              target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'

               end
          end
   end
end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Put "post_install" block outside of target block. After that install one more time.

For more info refer [documents](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html)

Comment: But still have same errors :(